# Delegate unique jQuery event handlers to child elements

Tags: jquery

Mootools has the following syntax for delegating unique event handlers to child elements of a given parent element using different event types. Does a similar syntax exist in jQuery? I'm trying to avoid writing a separate case for each element I want to attach an element to.

```
$('myElement').addEvents({
    // monitor an element for mouseover
    mouseover: fn,
    // but only monitor child links for clicks
    'click:relay(a)': fn2
});
```

I'm more interested in the second item being passed, which basically says "if I click on an anchor inside of #myElement, call this function." I can easily expand on this list to add more unique event handlers to other children using whatever event I'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I can think of is `on()`:

```
$('#myElement').on('mouseover', 'a', function(){
        // do something when an a element within the '#myElement' element is moused-over
    });
```

There's also `delegate()`, which achieves much the same, but uses slightly different syntax:

```
$('#myElement').delegate('a', 'mouseover', function(){
    // do something when the 'a' within the '#myElement' element is moused-over
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6nNvZ/1).

References:

- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks, David. I ended up doing what was in your JS Fiddle. I was just hoping that jQuery had a similarly terse syntax so I could do more in a single block of code, but oh well. :)

Comment: You're very welcome; I'm glad to have been of help! If you consider your question answered it would be good form to [accept the answer you find most-useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If your question *isn't* answered, though, don't feel compelled to accept.

Comment: @BradAzevedo. Hi bred, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.